# jquery mobile listview hide and show then cannot search

Tags: jquery, listview, search, mobile, hide

Using the Jquery Mobile 1.2 there is a problem where if you have a listview, and you hide and then show the child, the said child cannot be searched.

without tying to explain in words, see this:
http://jsfiddle.net/bodgybrothers/bw2ZV/

on load it creates two listview children and the search box. Then it hides and shows the second child. by searching this list, the second child is always shown even when it has no search match.

I believe it is a bug in jquery mobile, but wondered if there is a workaround to make all elements searchable after the show method.

```
$('#li-nav').append('<li id="1"><a href="#page1">Page 1</a></li>')
$('#li-nav').append('<li id="2"><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li>').listview('refresh');
$('#2').hide();
$('#2').show();
```

EDIT: I worked out a method which goes back to javascript rather than using the jquery library. The hide and show functions are shown below:

```
function showStuff(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = '';
}
function hideStuff(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
}
```

updated the JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bodgybrothers/uwnCY/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a workaround, but another easier fix (for those who had this same problem) - is to do a addClass("hide") or removeClass("hide")  instead of a .show / .hide. 
This no longer breaks the search.

```
css:
.hide {display:none;}   

JQuery: 
$('#li-nav').append('<li id="1"><a href="#page1">Page 1</a></li>');
$('#li-nav').append('<li id="2"><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li>');
$('#li-nav').listview('refresh');
$('#2').addClass('hide');
$('#2').removeClass('hide');
('<li>').listview('refresh');
```

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8Cfj/1/